# Flash / AS3 - Works in IDE But Strange Browser Behavior. Why?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Ok, I have a flash browser application that loads in a child swf using a Loader object. I thought adding a mouse click listener to the Loader object would allow me to listen for clicks on the object, but it doesn't. :/

I actually do see the clicked!!! being traced out when I am testing in my IDE (Flash Develop). However, when put in any browser the mouse handlers are never called. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Also, trying to access children of the loader object results in Security Sandbox Error.

```
public function Main() 
    {
        trace("Starting...");
        Security.allowDomain('*');
        Security.allowInsecureDomain('*');

        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point


        var inputFlashVars:Object = this.loaderInfo.parameters

        _swfLoader = new Loader();
        stage.addChild(_swfLoader);
        _swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoaded);


        var ldrContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true);
        ldrContext.checkPolicyFile = true;
        ldrContext.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
        //ldrContext.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain(new ApplicationDomain());

        var urlForVideoToPlay:String = AD_SWF_URL;
        trace("Loading swf: " + urlForVideoToPlay + " with click URL: " + CLICKTHROUGH_URL);

        _swfLoader.load(new URLRequest(urlForVideoToPlay), ldrContext);

    }


    private function onSwfLoaded(e:Event):void 
    {

        //var swfChild:* = _swfLoader.getChildAt(0);
        //_swfLoader.mouseChildren = false;
        trace(e.target);

        _swfLoader.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onInnerSwfClicked, false);
        _swfLoader.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onInnerSwfClicked, false);
        _swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoaded);
        trace("Ad swf loaded!");
    }

    private function onInnerSwfClicked(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace("clicked!!!");

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from your click listeners, you're attaching them to the wrong stage object:

```
_swfLoader.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onInnerSwfClicked, false);
_swfLoader.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onInnerSwfClicked, false);
```

When you load the child swif in a parent swif, the stage points to the parent swif. It works on debug mode because you're loading the child swif without a shell/parent.

Try this instead:

```
_swfLoader.content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onInnerSwfClicked, false);
_swfLoader.content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onInnerSwfClicked, false);
```

Comment: Entering _swfLoader.content causes a security error: SecurityError: Error #2121: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: http://127.0.0.1/thisSwfswf cannot access https://s0.2mdn.net/2644440/300x250_eas_display_campaign_v2.swf. This may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.
 at flash.display::Loader/get content()

Comment: And you need to make sure you crossdomain.xml policy is ok

Comment: My crossdomain of the swf doing the loading or the crossdomain for the server hosting the child swf?

Comment: The parent Swf Server needs to allow requests from the Server hosting the child swf

Comment: @Robuttst, is your own SWF file in some **HTTPS** server? the other SWf you are loading is located at **https: //s0.2mdn.net** etc so it means you cant just access its data from your own regular **http: //mysite** but you could do it if loading from your secure **httpS: //mysite**. No padlock icon for "secure" on your site means no loading other HTTPS server data..

Comment: Mind you looking at: https://s0.2mdn.net/crossdomain.xml the important line is this one: `<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>` seems to suggest if you load that crossdomain you should have normal access. Try again?? Security Sandbox is one of the biggest pains in the ass for AS3 coders